# Insert all subdirectories in Dired

Tags: dired

How can I insert all the subdirectories of the toplevel directory in Dired?

And how can I insert the whole directory tree, i.e. all the subdirectories recursively?

I don't want to change the default switches, only to insert all the subdirectories just this once.

I'm not looking for `C-u i` and adding the `R` switch: that inserts subdirectories of the directory under the cursor. I want to insert all the subdirectories of the main directory.

Comment: You can call `find-dired` with no arguments. It will create a dired buffer with all files and directories under a given top level directory.

Comment: Try `C-u s R RET`.

Comment: To elaborate on @politza's really good suggestion: `C-u s` is a really useful dired command that lets you edit dired's `ls` switches.

Answer (score 2):

If you use library [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) then this is simple.

Just use **`M-+ M-i`** (command **`diredp-insert-subdirs-recursive`**).

Alternatively, use menu `Multiple` > `Marked Here and Below` > `Insert Subdirs`.

Dired+ has many commands that act on the marked files and the marked files in marked subdirectories, gathered recursively.  And when none are marked, these commands act on ***all*** files in ***all*** subdirectories.  All such commands are on prefix key **`M-+`**.

Even if some files or subdirs are marked, such commands ignore the markings and act on ***all*** files in ***all*** subdirectories if you provide a *prefix argument*.

> **diredp-insert-subdirs-recursive** is an interactive compiled Lisp
>       function in **`dired+.el`**.
>
> (diredp-insert-subdirs-recursive &optional IGNORE-MARKS-P)
>
> Insert the marked subdirs, including those in marked subdirs.
>       Like `diredp-insert-subdirs`, but act recursively on subdirs.
>       The subdirs inserted are those that are marked in the current Dired
>       buffer, or ALL subdirs in the directory if none are marked.  Marked
>       subdirectories are handled recursively in the same way (their marked
>       subdirs are inserted...).
>
> With a prefix argument, ignore all marks - include all files in this
>       Dired buffer and all subdirs, recursively.